# API calls work locally, but not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, heroku

I have build some login token auth Apis using Ruby on Rails, it works well on local, I have a user built into the local and heroku database, and if I do this :

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"session":{"password":"12345678","email":"example@zapserver.com"}}' http://api.zapserver.dev/sessions/
```

I can get the correct JSON response from the server.

But, when I do the same call to Heroku, which would be something like this:

```
curl -k -v -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"session":{"password":"12345678","email":"example@zapserver.com"}}' https://api.appname.herokuapp.com/sessions/
```

I got a 404 Not Found error.

I have done the `rails db:migrate` and I still got the same error.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I got literally nothing from Heroku log, I used a `heroku logs --tail` command and nothing happened.

Here's the error message I got from the Curl:

```
*   Trying 50.19.245.201...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.zapserver.heroku.com (50.19.245.201) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.herokuapp.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
> POST /sessions/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.zapserver.heroku.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 67
> 
* upload completely sent off: 67 out of 67 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: Cowboy
< Date: Sun, 12 Feb 2017 14:30:09 GMT
< Content-Length: 494
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>No such app</title>
        <style media="screen">
          html,body,iframe {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          html,body {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/no-such-app.html"></iframe>
      </body>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host api.zapserver.heroku.com left intact
```

Comment: does your user exist on heroku yet?

Comment: `rake db:migrate`, not rails. Typo?

Comment: rails db:migrate is fine for rails 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that Heroku wants you to pay for the domain if you wanna use something like api.example.com, so I change the routing a bit from api.example.com to xxx.com/api in route.rb using:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '/api' do
```

instead of the code in my old route.rb

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/' do
```

And now if I do the Curl like this:

```
curl -k -v -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"session":{"password":"12345678","email":"example@zapserver.com"}}' https://example.com/api/sessions/
```

I can get the correct JSON back from the server.

Comment: hey DevArenaCN can u please solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67715660/localhost-api-work-properly-on-postman-but-heroku-api-is-not-working-atlas-mon

Answer (score 1):

It's the way domain routing works. When you own example.com, all requests to any address that end with this domain (e.g. mail.example.com, www.example.com, etc.) are routed to your configured DNS server. This server converts the address to an IP address based on the configuration of the DNS records.

The root of your domain, in this case, herokuapp.com is owned by Heroku, so when you create an app, they can create a DNS entry for that app and point it internally to your instance. There would be no mechanism in which application code running in a Heroku app would be able to create additional subdomains without giving some kind of API access to their internal networking configuration, which no company I can think of would ever allow. So essentially, this could never be a valid address: https://api.appname.herokuapp.com

If you create a custom domain, you can certainly use any address you like as long as it ends with your domain, but you'll still have to configure those names on your your new DNS host also.

So I would say that it has nothing to do with Heroku wanting to charge more, it's simply the way DNS works.

Comment: so u mean that if i call my api on postman, and my api is look like  https://api.attendance-demo.herokuapp.com/login, so r u sure it will response positive?

Answer (score 0):

404 error means that the page is not found and hence a routing error? Can you post your heroku logs for more detail? thx
Also, as mentioned below. rails db:migrate does not effect heroku DB. hence you would want to run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, and other rake comands

Comment: I've done that as well, still nothing. Also, there's nothing in the heroku log when I do the curl command. I've added the error message above

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that since this is a Rails 5 app then you should be using ```heroku run rails db:migrate```.  No more switching between ```rails``` and ```rake```.  This has nothing to do with the actual 404 problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not able to decode the user properly. I have the solid solution for this.

go to application_controller.rb

and in your authenticate method relplace the  code with this:

```
def authenticate_api_request
    header = request.headers['Authorization']
    header = header.split(' ').last if header
     begin
        # @decoded = JsonWebToken.decode(header)
        key = Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base. to_s 
        decoded = JWT.decode(header, key)[0]
        HashWithIndifferentAccess.new decoded
        @current_user = User.find(decoded.values[0])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
        render json: { errors: e.message }, status: :unauthorized
      rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
        render json: { errors: e.message }, status: :unauthorized
     end 
  end
```